# Where should I ask a question on OSCE's (international organization's) recruitment process?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, jobs, politics

I have been sent here from the Politics SE as my question was off topic there.

I am not sure where to ask this question, so I am giving it a shot here. I am trying to apply for a position with the [OSCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organization_for_Security_and_Co-operation_in_Europe) and have filled in my profile. On the tab where I can print my profile to see what it looks like, the system has removed all the bullet points and paragraphs that I have filled in originally (see pics). I know how picky the organization is with even considering applications, which is why I would like to know if this layout issue in the printed version even matters or not. If I had to change everything from bullet points to full sentences, I would imagine it would be much more difficult for the recruiter to extract the applicant’s skillset. On the other hand, if the recruiter had the same strange layout as displayed here, he/she might not consider the application because it looks unprofessional. I have attempted to email recruiting a couple months ago but never received any response and wouldn’t know anywhere else to ask.

I would really like to get into this position and any help is very much appreciated, ideally coming from recruiters from an international organization, or from someone working for the OSCE. I apologize, if this is the wrong forum to post this in! If so, it would be great, if you could redirect me to the correct forum.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems like a question only someone who works for OSCE could answer, as it seems to mostly be a bug report for their recruiting software.  I don't think you're likely to find a Stack Exchange site where it would fit.

Comment: Does it occur to @p.Mort that sometimes errors are typos–the rest of the text capitalizes the singular first person pronoun correctly–and rather than proselytize in the edit summary  they can just fix the typo.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I know they make tons of edits like this, with very helpful descriptions. The edit description is probably copy paste.

Comment: "I would imagine it would be much more difficult for the recruiter to extract the applicant’s skillset." Why do you assume this? They designed the system this way, so no applicant will be able to use bullet points. It seems like this issue has been blocking you from submitting the application for months. I'd strongly suggest that you convert to full sentences. I would assume that content matters much more than form here.

Answer (score 9):

That specific question will not fit on any site within the Stack Exchange Network.

The question and an answer is applicable to you and maybe a few others. That is in general a good indicator SE is not the right venue.

On top of that it is unlikely that you will even get an authoritative answer here. I don't expect support staff of that company/organisation to patrol the SE sites (or any other site for that matter) to look for reported issues. And then I am assuming the software/hosting that runs that application form isn't outsourced. If a random stranger on the internet says: *Yeah, no problem it will work* and your application is rejected for being an layout mess then that is not helpful (if not harmful to you).

That said, a strategy you could follow is simply contacting the organisation and explain your concern. At least where I live it generally is not a problem if you raise a question prior to your application. I assume you make that first contact worthwhile so you are remembered for the good bits ...

I haven't checked thoroughly but maybe [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) offers solutions / strategies for contacting a potential employer ahead of your application. Let me re-iterate that you can't ask your specific question on the Workplace but you could ask (search first!) for something like: *Should I contact an potential employer if I notice a technical/functional problem in their online application form* or something better formulated along those lines. Stay away from asking for a resolution for your specific case. That is off-topic on The Workplace.